# PHP - DateTimeZone error

Tags: php

I'm using functions with the datetime object that require a datetimezone object as an argument.
why datetime error ?
helpme please.

```
<?php
$sunrise = $r['resto_time1'];
$sunset = $r['resto_time2'];
$time_zone = $r['time_zone'];
$dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
$current_time = $dateTime->format('H:i A');
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $current_time);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $sunrise);
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $sunset);
if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3)
{
echo 'open';
}
else {
    echo "Close";
}

?>
```

why datetime error ?
help me please.

Comment: what is  value of variable  `$sunrise`, `$sunset` and `$time_zone`

Comment: What is the error? and can you please tell us what you are getting in `$r['time_zone']`??

Comment: $sunrise = "05:30 am";
$sunset = "03:00 pm";
$time_zone ="asia/jakarta"; 
but in array mysql

Comment: How do you fetch the details from database? Seems an error in retrieving details from database. There isn't any error in your code.

Comment: what u want in output?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTimeZone::__construct() [<a href='datetimezone.--construct'>datetimezone.--construct</a>]: Unknown or bad timezone ($r[time_zone])' in /home/foodiegu/public_html/restaurant_detail.php:217 Stack trace: #0 /home/foodiegu/public_html/restaurant_detail.php(217): DateTimeZone->__construct('$r[time_zone]') #1 {main}

Comment: It looks like you have the value `$r[time_zone]` stored in your database instead of `asia/jakarta` which is causing the error.

Comment: echo "$time_zone";

asia/jakarta

without '/"

Comment: if $time_zone="asia/jakarta"; no error

Comment: if $time_zone=$r['time_zone'];   error

Comment: Firstly, welcome to SO! Now, your constructor throws an exception -- add that info to your question instead of using comments, you can still edit it now. Further, what are the exact parameters you pass to that constructor? Finding that out should be the first step when debugging! Also, before posting you should have a minimal but complete example, because that's what the posting guidelines actually require from you.